# Why does Firefox render padding around numbers in right-to-left text?

Tags: html, css, firefox

When adding horizontal padding to a right-to-left inline-block, using [box-decoration-break](https://callmenick.com/dev/multi-line-padded-text-css-box-decoration-break/) for a highlighting effect, Firefox renders an extra layer of padding around any number.

Increasing the horizontal padding, which should only add to the beginning and end of each line, also increases the padding around the number in the middle of the line.

Why is this happening? This doesn't seem like the expected behavior.

**HTML**

```
<div dir="rtl" lang="fa-IR"><span>من 123 ساله هستم</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
span {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 85px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/johanhh/pen/yqXOJR)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilIWb.png)

Comment: it renders fine on my side on the code pen. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Firefox adds padding around the number, and Webkit doesn't. Firefox screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/UcG4MHq

Comment: Looks like a font-face issue.  Have you tired specifying a `font-family`?  The defaults for each browser may just kern numbers differently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have, unfortunately, and `font-family` seems to have no effect.

Comment: Increasing the horizontal padding, which should only add to the ends of each line, also increases the padding around the number in the middle of the line.

Comment: Hi, i think is because the text language, if you use english or spanish charset there is no problem.